# StringTemplate use of listItem

Tags: jar, stringtemplate

I'm trying to get the simple example to work, here is the sample code .stg file

```
group list-demo;

htmListExample(xmen) ::= <<
Example 5:
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Original X-Men</h1>
        <ul>
            $xmen:listItem()$
        </ul>
        </body>
    </html>

    >>

    listItem() ::= <<
    <li>$it$</li>
>>
```

My Java code:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile("/myTemplate2.stg",'$','$');
ST template = group.getInstanceOf("htmListExample");
List<String> xmen = Arrays.asList("Jean Gray", "Cyclops");
template.add("xmen", xmen);
System.out.println(template.render().toString());
```

And the output:

```
 context [/htmListExample] 6:18 passed 1 arg(s) to template /listItem with 0 declared arg(s)
 context [/htmListExample] 6:13 passed 1 arg(s) to template /listItem with 0 declared arg(s)
 context [/htmListExample] 6:13 passed 1 arg(s) to template /listItem with 0 declared arg(s)
 context [/htmListExample /listItem] 2:5 attribute it isn't defined
 context [/htmListExample /listItem] 2:5 attribute it isn't defined
Example 5:
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Original X-Men</h1>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why the listItem() is not recognized? I'm using the ST-4.0.7.jar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In StringTemplate 4, the map operator `:` maps a collection to a template that takes one argument. You need to declare the `it` argument for the `listItem` template:

```
listItem(it) ::= <<
<li>$it$</li>
>>
```

The warnings which you saw in the output say this:

1. ST4 expected a template with 1 parameter, but you passed it `listItem` which takes 0 parameters.
2. You didn't declare the `it` parameter, but you referenced it within `listItem`.

Comment: Yep. That's it.  I guess I was looking up an old example.  Thanks.